# start-dfs.sh and Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, ssh

Failed start-dfs.sh:

```
nikita@master:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ ./start-dfs.sh

Starting namenodes on [master]
ERROR: namenode can only be executed by root.
Starting datanodes
ERROR: datanode can only be executed by root.
Starting secondary namenodes [master]
ERROR: secondarynamenode can only be executed by root.

nikita@master:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ sudo ./start-dfs.sh

Starting namenodes on [master]
master: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Starting datanodes
localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Starting secondary namenodes [master]
master: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

run `ssh master` - OK;
run `sudo ssh master` - Permission denied

How to solve?
How run start-dfs.sh without 'sudo'?

Comment: `namenode can only be executed by root`, therefore, you'll need sudo, but the root user must have a passwordless SSH key to the system, otherwise you get permission denied

Comment: we can not start this command using sudo, else i am getting error like:                                Stopping namenodes on [pd-master]
ERROR: Attempting to operate on hdfs namenode as root
ERROR: but there is no HDFS_NAMENODE_USER defined. Aborting operation.
Stopping datanodes..... any other Options ?

Comment: @WojciechPawlik Literally `sudo ./start-dfs.sh`? And, as mentioned, create `ssh-keygen -P''` as root user and use `ssh-copy-id <other nodes>` to fix `Permission denied (...)`... And to fix the error from Bimal, simply read the error... Set that env-variable in `hadoop-env.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Enter root shell and create an SSH key

```
$ sudo su -
# ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
# cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
# chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Verify connection

```
# ssh localhost
# ssh master
```

If the second doesn't work, then remove `127.0.1.1 master` entry from `/etc/hosts`. Ensure you only have `master` (your hostname) in line `127.0.0.1 master localhost`

Then, if you have other nodes in the cluster, you need to use `ssh-copy-id` to copy your authorized keys to those.

Then `sudo` should work.

Otherwise, [docs do not say `sudo/root` is necessary](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html).

Personally, I prefer using [`hdfs --daemon start` scripts](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html#Operating_the_Hadoop_Cluster)